# Facebook comments works with URL /index.php?cID=122 but not /blog/myblogpost

Tags: comments, facebook-comments, concrete5

In concrete5 (PHP CMS) I created a basic Facebook comment block which works perfectly when the URL is in the form http://mysite.com/index.php?cID=122  but not when the URL is http://mysite.com/blog/myblogpost (which is the canonical URL). When using the canonical URL the facebook comments initiates, the three pulsing boxes that indicate loading appear, then the section vanished and displays nothing; there is no error. Being logged into concrete5 makes no difference.

Adding code to include the canonical URL in the href parameter of the  section did not change this behaviour.

I don't know if this is a Concrete5 quirk or a problem with the way I'm using the Facebook code, can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

The block of code looks like this:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<fb:comments href="http://mysite.com/blog/myblogpost"></fb:comments>
<script type="text/javascript">  FB.init(MYAPIKEYHERE, "xd_receiver.htm"); </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FeatureLoader.js.php is deprecated (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/) and you should use the all-new Javascript SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript).

Please recode with that and it should fix your issue.